# Custom Markup Extension for Data Context Always Treated as type System.Object

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, markup-extensions

I'm trying to create a custom XAML markup extension that will take a type as an argument, and at runtime, resolve that type using an IoC container, but at design time, simply create it using the default constructor. For now, I'm just trying to implement the default constructor portion. It will look like this:

```
<UserControl ...
             DataContext="{custom:MyCustomExtension MyType}"

    <TextBox Text="{Binding SomeProperty}" />
</UserControl>
```

The issue is that the designer always treats the value my extension produces as type object, so I can't use the GUI binding tools, yet it works fine during runtime.

[image: Binding Tools Failing]

Here's my very basic implementation to reproduce the issue.

```
[MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(object))]
public class MyCustomExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    [ConstructorArgument("dataContextType")]
    public Type DataContextType { get; set; }

    public MyCustomExtension () {  }

    public MyCustomExtension (Type dataContextType)
    {
        DataContextType = dataContextType;
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return Activator.CreateInstance(DataContextType);
    }
}
```

I've tried using reflector to study how `StaticResourceExtension` does it, because while it also has the `[MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(object))]` attribute, the VS designer has no issue using the real type of the resource being referenced, but couldn't find anything special using that route.

Comment: try if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this)) then give designer instance or resolve using dependency resolver.

Comment: @RAJ That comes later. My question is about solving a designer issue before it ever comes to the IoC implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your custom markup extension in Blend (Microsoft Blend for Visual Studio Professional 2015) and it worked for me:

[image: Working]

The change in this "Create Data Binding" window is only visible after a rebuild.

My XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="DesignTimeTypedDataContext.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DesignTimeTypedDataContext"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        DataContext="{local:MyCustom {x:Type local:MainWindowViewModel}}">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="14.862,19.706,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Text}" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

BTW, I guess you know this, but there is `d:DataContext` which gives you a design time `DataContext` without affecting the runtime.

```
<Window x:Class="DesignTimeTypedDataContext.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DesignTimeTypedDataContext"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type local:MainWindowViewModel}}">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="14.862,19.706,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Maybe this is not much of an answer, just thought I'd share it, maybe it helps in debugging. Now at least you that know your code works for some :)

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. I do not use blend, so I can't say if it works there or not. I'm using Visual Studio 2015, and am trying to get it to work there.  I am aware of the design-time datacontext tag, but I'm planning on using this extension for far more than just the data context property, so I can't depend on that "magic tag".